# what are the correct /var permisions on ubuntu 9.04?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions

I was resetting permissions on /var/www and screwed it up!

Now I get frequent problems connecting to mysql, using the package manager because /var has fairly open permissions.

Anyone know if /var is a fairly blanket

```
sudo chmod -R 700 *
```

Help!

Comment: You will ruin your system if you do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most directories should be 755 and owned by root. Sadly not everything should be that. If you do a recursive permission change, you will do significantly more damage. On my machine, I have:

```
mojo-jojo david% sudo find /var -type d ! -perm 755 -ls
278532    4 drwxrwsr-x   2 root     staff        4096 Oct 20  2008 /var/local
286930    4 drwx-wx--T   2 root     crontab      4096 Sep  9  2008 /var/spool/cron/crontabs
286848    4 drwxrwx--T   2 daemon   daemon       4096 Jul 10  2008 /var/spool/cron/atspool
286849    4 drwxrwx--T   2 daemon   daemon       4096 Oct 21  2008 /var/spool/cron/atjobs
319499    4 drwx--x---   3 root     lp           4096 Oct 21  2008 /var/spool/cups
319500    4 drwxrwx--T   2 root     lp           4096 Oct 20  2008 /var/spool/cups/tmp
352575    4 drwxr-x---   5 Debian-exim Debian-exim     4096 Mar 28 09:03 /var/spool/exim4
352624    4 drwxr-x---   2 Debian-exim Debian-exim     4096 Aug  5 07:02 /var/spool/exim4/msglog
352622    4 drwxr-x---   2 Debian-exim Debian-exim     4096 Dec 14  2008 /var/spool/exim4/db
352623    4 drwxr-x---   2 Debian-exim Debian-exim     4096 Aug  5 07:02 /var/spool/exim4/input
279126    4 drwxrwsr-x   2 libuuid  libuuid      4096 Oct 21  2008 /var/lib/libuuid
352603    4 drwxrwx---   2 logcheck logcheck     4096 Oct 22  2008 /var/lib/logcheck
320214    4 drwxrwx---   2 root     polkituser     4096 Oct 21  2008 /var/lib/PolicyKit
352614    4 drwxrwxr-x   2 munin    munin        4096 May  3 09:05 /var/lib/munin/plugin-state
270524    4 drwx------  10 postgres postgres     4096 Jul 29 04:07 /var/lib/postgresql/8.3/main
270533    4 drwx------   2 postgres postgres     4096 Dec 12  2008 /var/lib/postgresql/8.3/main/pg_twophase
270540    4 drwx------   7 postgres postgres     4096 Dec 13  2008 /var/lib/postgresql/8.3/main/base
1106278    4 drwx------   2 postgres postgres     4096 Dec 18  2008 /var/lib/postgresql/8.3/main/base/pgsql_tmp
311894    4 drwx------   2 postgres postgres     4096 Jul 29 04:07 /var/lib/postgresql/8.3/main/base/11511
270542    4 drwx------   2 postgres postgres     4096 Dec 12  2008 /var/lib/postgresql/8.3/main/base/1
270937    4 drwx------   2 postgres postgres     4096 Mar 28 09:29 /var/lib/postgresql/8.3/main/base/16385
311320    4 drwx------   2 postgres postgres     4096 Dec 12  2008 /var/lib/postgresql/8.3/main/base/11510
270543    4 drwx------   2 postgres postgres     4096 Dec 12  2008 /var/lib/postgresql/8.3/main/pg_tblspc
270527    4 drwx------   2 postgres postgres     4096 Aug  5 08:32 /var/lib/postgresql/8.3/main/global
270528    4 drwx------   3 postgres postgres     4096 Dec 17  2008 /var/lib/postgresql/8.3/main/pg_xlog
270529    4 drwx------   2 postgres postgres     4096 Dec 12  2008 /var/lib/postgresql/8.3/main/pg_xlog/archive_status
270535    4 drwx------   4 postgres postgres     4096 Dec 12  2008 /var/lib/postgresql/8.3/main/pg_multixact
270538    4 drwx------   2 postgres postgres     4096 Dec 12  2008 /var/lib/postgresql/8.3/main/pg_multixact/offsets
270536    4 drwx------   2 postgres postgres     4096 Dec 12  2008 /var/lib/postgresql/8.3/main/pg_multixact/members
270532    4 drwx------   2 postgres postgres     4096 Dec 12  2008 /var/lib/postgresql/8.3/main/pg_subtrans
270530    4 drwx------   2 postgres postgres     4096 Dec 12  2008 /var/lib/postgresql/8.3/main/pg_clog
321312    4 drwxrwx--T   3 root     gdm          4096 Jul 29 08:17 /var/lib/gdm
1729012    4 drwx------   2 mysql    mysql        4096 Feb  3  2009 /var/lib/mysql/newforms_sess
1728971    4 drwx------   2 mysql    mysql        4096 Feb 16 21:38 /var/lib/mysql/newforms
369895    4 drwxrwxr-x   3 root     tomcat6      4096 Dec 17  2008 /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps
270506    4 drwxr-x---  15 root     root         4096 Apr 25 11:50 /var/lib/puppet/clientbucket
271123    4 drwxrwx---   3 root     root         4096 Apr 18 13:51 /var/lib/puppet/clientbucket/*
270483    4 drwxrwx--x   6 root     root         4096 Mar 28 19:21 /var/lib/puppet/ssl
270490    4 drwxr-x---   2 root     root         4096 Mar 28 19:21 /var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys
270488    4 drwxr-x---   2 root     root         4096 Mar 28 19:21 /var/lib/puppet/ssl/private
270481    4 drwxr-xr-t   2 root     root         4096 Aug  5 08:18 /var/lib/puppet/state
534313    0 drwx------   3 root     Domain Users       60 Jul 29 21:30 /var/run/sudo
534314    0 drwx------   2 root     Domain Users      100 Aug  5 08:32 /var/run/sudo/david
  9242    0 dr-x--x--x   2 lp       lpadmin        40 Aug  5 07:43 /var/run/cups/certs
  8006    0 drwxrwxrwt   2 puppet   puppet         60 Aug  2 07:43 /var/run/puppet
  7877    0 drwxr-x---   2 root     winbindd_priv       60 Aug  2 08:26 /var/run/samba/winbindd_privileged
  7463    0 drwxr-x---   2 Debian-exim Debian-exim       60 Jul 29 04:07 /var/run/exim4
  6880    0 drwxrwsr-x   2 postgres postgres      100 Jul 29 04:07 /var/run/postgresql
  6172    0 drwxrwx---   2 root     polkituser       40 Jul 29 04:07 /var/run/PolicyKit
  6016    0 drwxrwxr-x   2 root     utmp           40 Jul 29 04:07 /var/run/screen
278583    4 drwxrwsr-x   2 root     mail         4096 Oct 21  2008 /var/mail
327995    4 drwxrwxrwt   2 root     root         4096 Apr  9 07:35 /var/crash
278535    4 drwxrwxrwt   2 root     root         4096 Aug  2 10:34 /var/tmp
  2878    0 drwxrwxrwt   4 root     root          100 Aug  5 07:43 /var/lock
320430    4 drwxrwxr-x   4 root     lp           4096 Mar 28 09:12 /var/cache/cups
320432    4 drwxrwxr-x   2 root     lp           4096 Oct 20  2008 /var/cache/cups/rss
278548    4 drwx------   2 root     root         4096 Aug  5 08:30 /var/cache/ldconfig
271257    4 drwx------   2 tomcat55 adm          4096 Nov 18  2008 /var/cache/tomcat5.5
287018    4 drwxr-sr-x  44 man      root         4096 Aug  5 07:43 /var/cache/man
287178    4 drwxr-sr-x   2 man      root         4096 Aug  5 07:43 /var/cache/man/*
541847    4 drwxr-x---   3 tomcat6  adm          4096 Jun 20 18:43 /var/cache/tomcat6
327693    4 drwxrwsr-t   2 root     admin        4096 Oct 21  2008 /var/cache/jockey
352620    4 drwxr-s---   2 Debian-exim adm          4096 Aug  5 07:43 /var/log/exim4
328117    4 drwxr-x---   3 root     adm          4096 Aug  2 07:43 /var/log/samba
353025    4 drwx------   3 root     root         4096 Oct 22  2008 /var/log/samba/cores
353026    4 drwx------   2 root     root         4096 Oct 22  2008 /var/log/samba/cores/winbindd
279487    4 drwxr-sr-x   2 news     news         4096 Oct 21  2008 /var/log/news
352612    4 drwxr-x---   2 munin    adm          4096 Aug  5 07:43 /var/log/munin
311823    4 drwxrwxr-t   2 root     postgres     4096 Aug  2 07:43 /var/log/postgresql
288323    4 drwxr-x---   2 tomcat55 adm          4096 Aug  4 07:52 /var/log/tomcat5.5
328912    4 drwxr-x---   2 root     adm          4096 Aug  2 07:43 /var/log/apache2
328064    4 drwxr-s---   2 mysql    adm          4096 Jan 29  2009 /var/log/mysql
369892    4 drwxr-x---   2 tomcat6  adm          4096 Aug  4 07:52 /var/log/tomcat6
294961    4 drwxr-x---   2 puppet   puppet       4096 Aug  2 07:43 /var/log/puppet
```

There will be many more files with different permissions. Hopefully this gives you some idea of what to fix.

Answer (score 1):

You say package manager, I'm guessing you're running Ubuntu?  Unfortunately, if you're running an apt-based distro, then you'll have to do it manually like David states.

If you're running an RPM-based distro, you can do this:

```
for p in $(rpm -qa); do rpm --setperms $p; done
for p in $(rpm -qa); do rpm --setugids $p; done
```

That's one of the few advantages RPM has over deb/apt.

Comment: I did it manually. It took ages.

Comment: Given that the solution involves doing something over the whole list of installed packages, you can probably get the practically same effect by doing `apt-get install --reinstall $(dpkg -l | awk '/^.i/ {print $2}')` - assuming `/var/lib/debconf`, `/var/lib/apt`, `/var/cache/apt` and `/var/lib/dpkg` aren't horribly messed up, all it will mean is a lot of package fetching and answering trivial conffile prompts